# Pass variable from PHP to jQuery POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to track page referrals, so I might have a URL like:

```
www.example.com/?ref=google
```

I've successfully captured that referral as a variable like so:

```
if ($_GET['ref'] !== "") {
    $ref = $_GET['ref'];
}
else {
    $ref = "";
}
```

How can I pass it through my jQuery POST function?

```
$.post("signup.php", {email: email, ref: /* what goes here */}, function(data){
                $("#validation-message").text(data).addClass("error-text");
            });
```

I've read about `json_encode()` but is that just for arrays?

Comment: You already have access to that value in PHP through `$_GET`. Why would you need JS to send it to PHP too?

Comment: echo out the value

Comment: whatever your php script writes to the document is received by jquery response

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan because I'm using jQuery to avoid a page refresh when submitting the form. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Put the `$_GET['ref']` in a session.

Comment: `ref: /* what goes here */` - well what would go there, if you wanted to send just a static text? Once you answer that (rather trivial) question, you also know what output you need your PHP to generate in this place ...

Comment: `$.post("signup.php", {email: email, ref: '<?php echo $ref; ?>'}, function(data){
                $("#validation-message").text(data).addClass("error-text");
            });
`

Comment: another option is to save in a session and not pass it back and forth between server ad client.

Comment: I answered you before in comment but incase you need another concept or better explanation read my answer below

Answer (score 4):

You can `echo` the variable to pass it to js.

```
var ref = '<?php echo $ref; ?>'; /*Assigning the php value to js*/

$.post("signup.php", {email: email, ref: ref }, function(data){
       $("#validation-message").text(data).addClass("error-text");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo out the php value into an input hidden textbox value, and call it out via jQuery or assign it to a js value, there are so many ways to do it. It all depends on how and what you want to achieve